# How do i scale a ggplot in R so that the y axis starts from 0?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

## I created a dataframe, DF.

```
date <- c("2018-06-25", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-26", "2018-06- 
27", "2018-06-27")

temperature <- c("15", "18", "16", "17", "14", "15")

DF <- data.frame(date, temperature)
```

I want to plot temperature over the different dates using ggplot.

How do I adapt my code below, so that the scale on the y-axis starts at 0.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(date, temperature))+geom_point() + ggtitle('Temperature plot')
```

[Link to temperature plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNdy1.png)

Comment: @PoGibas The solution within that link, does not work for my problem

Comment: I think the problem is that `temperature` is not numeric, thus you cant use the conventional `scale_xxx` or `xlim` functions. Try changing them to numeric. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280280/2625032). After converting, you should be able to do `... + ylim(0, upper)` and it should work. __edit__: just tired it, confirmed working :thumbsup:

Comment: @hello_world okay! That works for me too. Thanks!