# Segment/Point ggplot2 is reversing x & y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a segment/point plot that has the topBatter on the Y axis and the topTen Distance on the Y axis. When I create it the plot reverses the X and Y.

I'm a bit stuck as to why this one isn't working.

Thanks for any guidance. I appreciate this community.

> 

```
#Top HR by Distance
topTenDistance <- c(485, 502, 484, 492, 489, 499, 500, 497, 489, 501)
topBatter <- c("Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Fa", "Ga", "Ha", "Ja", "Ka", "Ya", "Ja")
topCombined <- cbind(topBatter, topTenDistance)
topCombined <- as.data.frame(topCombined)

topCombined %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=topTenDistance, y=topBatter)) +
  geom_segment( aes(xend=topTenDistance, yend=0)) +
  geom_point( size=1.5, color="#134A8E") +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Top HRs by Distance") +
  labs(subtitle = "MLB 2022 Season") +
  xlab("Player's Name") +
  ylab("Distance (in ft")
```

> 

[image]

Comment: `batter_last_name` is a factor, not a continuous variable.  Hence the error.  Also, I strongly usrge you not to use `limits` to define the limits of your axes.  This filters the data and then constructs summaries, which can lead to unexpected and erroneous results.  `coord_cartesian` is *far* better, IMHO, because it uses the whole dataset to construct the graph and then "zooms" to the required region.

Comment: See, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278153/plotting-with-ggplot2-error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale-on-c)

Comment: This didn't work. It put the batter_name along the X and the distance along the Y even though x = distance and y = batter_name. 

I did this before without any issues when ranking album sales. Album was a character though but that also didn't work here.

Comment: Then we need a minimal reproducible example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct one.

Comment: `coord_flip()` flips the axes. If you don't want the axes flipped, don't use `coord_flip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  First, after

```
topTenDistance <- c(485, 502, 484, 492, 489, 499, 500, 497, 489, 501)
topBatter <- c("Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Fa", "Ga", "Ha", "Ja", "Ka", "Ya", "Ja")
topCombined <- cbind(topBatter, topTenDistance)
topCombined <- as.data.frame(topCombined)
```

`topCombined$topTenDistance` is character:

```
as_tibble(topCombined)
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   topBatter topTenDistance
   <chr>     <chr>         
 1 Ba        485           
 2 Ca        502           
 3 Da        484           
 4 Fa        492           
 5 Ga        489           
 6 Ha        499           
 7 Ja        500           
 8 Ka        497           
 9 Ya        489           
10 Ja        501
```

That's not helping.  So construct your data.frame like this:

```
topCombined <- data.frame(
                 topTenDistance=c(485, 502, 484, 492, 489, 499, 500, 497, 489, 501),
                 opBatter=c("Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Fa", "Ga", "Ha", "Ja", "Ka", "Ya", "Ja")
               )
```

Then

```
topCombined %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=topTenDistance, y=topBatter)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=480, yend=topBatter)) +
  geom_point( size=1.5, color="#134A8E") +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  ggtitle("Top HRs by Distance") +
  labs(subtitle = "MLB 2022 Season") +
  ylab("Player's Name") +
  xlab("Distance (in ft)")
```

produces

[image]

Is this what you want?  You can set the value of `xend` in the call to `geom_segment` to be whatever you find aesthetically pleasing.

Note that the "double dot" for `Ja` is a feature of your test data.

Incidentally,

```
topCombined %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=topBatter)) +
    geom_linerange(aes(xmin=480, xmax=topTenDistance)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=topTenDistance), size=1.5, color="#134A8E") +
    labs(
      title="Top HRs by Distance",
      subtitle = "MLB 2022 Season",
      y="Player's Name",
      x="Distance (in ft)"
    )
```

produces the same graph with a slightly simplified pipe.

Comment: The first code solution you shared yielded the same results. However, the 2nd code solution works. This is very odd to me.